# error when installing PDFNetPython3==8.1.0 for my pyrthon virtual environment

Tags: python, pycharm

When I try to install `PDFNetPython3==8.1.0` with pip on the `pycharm` command window I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PDFNetPython3==8.1.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PDFNetPython3==8.1.0
```

I expected that the Python package will be installed. Please can someone help me with the possible reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the release history for this Python package on the Python Package Index (PyPI) that pip uses when downloading packages: https://pypi.org/project/PDFNetPython3/#history

There is no version 8.1.0 available, either because it never was uploaded or because it was there but the author deleted it later on.

Comment: Thank you for your response .Thesame error occur with the version PDFNetPython3 9.5.0.post2 and also 9.4.2

Comment: @NkonghoNdip Which Python version do you use?

Comment: If you don't add a version requirement, the error should be a different one. Have you tried `pip install PDFNetPython3`? What does it say?